# Chinese character 数 encodes into too many bytes

Tags: java, localization

I'm trying to encode some Chinese characters using the GB18030 cp in Java, and I ran into this character 数, which translates to "Number" in Google Translate.

The issue is, it's turning into 10 bytes (!) when encoded:

81 30 81 34 81 30 83 31 ca fd

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
public class Test3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {        
        String s = new String("数");
        System.out.println( "source file: "+String.format("%x ", 
                new BigInteger(1, s.getBytes(Charset.forName("GB18030"))) ));       
    }    
}
```

When I try to decode that using the GB18030, it results in ? characters appearing beside the Chinese Number character (??数). When I try to decode only "CA FD", the last two bytes from above, it correctly decodes to the character.

Google translate notes the above character is Simplified. My source file is also saved in UTF8.

I thought GB18030 has a max of 4 bytes per character? Is there any particular reason this character behaves so strangely? (I'm not Chinese, BTW)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my encoding code's basically s.getBytes(Charset.forName("GB18030"). I'm running the snippet up there in a plain java main with nothing else.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah spot on with the U+6570! Looks like it's my source file. strange though as I've set eclipse to use UTF8. Must be getting corrupted somewhere. I'll just check it with a hex editor.

Comment: a downvote for the missing includes? I actually removed them on purpose didn't want to clutter the post, sorry.

Comment: @ Renan: Ah, good, glad that was it. Yeah, either encoding or you have characters in the string that don't render visually in your editor. The code in the question, copied-and-pasted, just outputs "ca fd".

Comment: @ Renan: Two lines to make things correctly compile is not clutter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely things are either:

1. There's an issue with the encoding of your source file, or
2. You have "invisible" characters prior to the 数 in it.

You can check both of those by completely deleting the string literal on this line:

```
String s = new String("数");
```

so it looks like this (note I removed the quotes as well as the character):

```
String s = new String();
```

and then adding back `"\u6570"` to get this:

```
String s = new String("\u6570");
```

and seeing if your output changes (as 数 is Unicode code point [U+6570](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=6570) and so that escape sequence should be the same character). If it changes, either there's an encoding problem or you had invisible characters in the string prior to the character. You can probably differentiate the two cases by then adding back just that character (via copy and paste from this page rather than your previous source code). If the problem reappears, it's an encoding issue. If not, you had hidden characters.